# Wordpress scheduled post created by java

Tags: java, wordpress, schedule

I can add new posts with the wordpress scheduler in java. I noticed with the wordpress scheduling article it will create a json in cron

```
a: 8: {
    i: 1542092341;a: 1: {
        s: 19: "publish_future_post";a: 1: {
            s: 32: "c8bde69a9f79ca24059e3807f9a3bcf8";a: 2: {
                s: 8: "schedule";b: 0;s: 4: "args";a: 1: {
                    i: 0;i: 10;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    i: 1542092385;a: 1: {
        s: 19: "publish_future_post";a: 1: {
            s: 32: "25117f4b9fd9bb6384d0eb8ea708c8b9";a: 2: {
                s: 8: "schedule";b: 0;s: 4: "args";a: 1: {
                    i: 0;i: 12;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    s: 7: "version";i: 2;
}
```

What are their meanings and how can I simulate them with java.Please help me

Comment: do you mean JavaScript? Java and JavaScript are two totally different things.

Comment: Maybe not good english, i want to ask how I can create a schedule for wordpress posts with java